# Aligning a cell to the center of the sheet in apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is it possible to to align a cell so that it is placed at the center of the worksheet?
I am creating a row and cell and setting some cell value. I am aware that the contents of a cell can be aligned to be placed at the top/center/bottom of a cell. However, I want the cell to be placed at the center of the worksheet.

I have tried using the following line of code but, I am not sure if that does the trick -

```
Row row= sheet.createRow(5);
Cell cell= row.createCell(6);
heading.setCellValue("Test Value");
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(6);
```

Comment: I don't thing Apache POI has a function specifically for that purpose. But if you are interested, max columns of .xls format is 256 which doesn't have a center unless you merge columns 128 and 129 and 65,536 rows. 16,384 columns for .xlsx format which doesn't have a center either and 1,048,576 rows.

Comment: @MichaelArdan So, if I want a create a cell in the middle of the sheet, then I have to do this? `Cell cell= row.createCell(128);`
and use `sheet.addMergedregion(newCellRangeAddress(5,6,128,129))` ?

Comment: Quite correct. You would also need to merge the row 32,768 to 32,769 in order to create the center of rows. sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(32768,32769,128,129) would do the trick. Note that this will only work on .xls file format. Maximum number of row and column is different on the recent update. This wouldn't be that complicated if you could get the lastRowNum of the sheet. However, you would only get the last row and column of a sheet if all the cells are created which I'm sure will eat your memory.